# Automapper through multiple maps

Tags: c#, .net, mapping, automapper

I want to do this:

int -> Card -> CardDto

I have this configuration for int -> Card:

```
        CreateMap<int, Card>().ConvertUsing(i => dictAllCards.ContainsKey(i) ? dictAllCards[i] :
            new Card
            {
                name = "Unknown"
            });
```

and this configuration for Card -> CardDto:

```
        CreateMap<Card, CardDto>();
```

Now if I want to convert an int directly to CardDto, I tried to do simply:

```
        CreateMap<int, CardDto>();
```

but I get a mapper error.

If I do

```
        CreateMap<int, CardDto>()
            .ConvertUsing(i => Mapper.Map<CardDto>(Mapper.Map<Card>(i)))
```

then everything works.

I would like to know if it is normal to have to define the last mapper with `ConvertUsing` and use Mapper.Map inside its mapping with the intermediate mapping...or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, AM will only apply one map. You should move away from the static mapper (gone in 9.0). Use `context.Mapper` instead.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Thanks for your answer, do you know where I can learn more about `context.Mapper`? This new information to me and in the docs (https://automapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Getting-started.html) I did not find anything...thanks :)

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu if you don't mind providing a complete answer with the correct usage of context.Mapper and best syntax to use (not sure if nesting 2 mappers like that is very good...), it would be much appreciated thanks